# C++ - MFC - Change text of a CMenu

Tags: c++, mfc

Good morning everybody,

I created an application that manages multi-language. When I dynamically change the default language of the application, all the text of the different graphic components change very well excepted one component. I don't know why ?

I tried those lines for modifying the text of the menu title but it changes only if I put my mouse on this menu.

```
MENUITEMINFO info;

info.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);

info.fMask = MIIM_ID;



VERIFY(AfxGetMainWnd()->GetMenu()->GetMenuItemInfoA(0, &info, TRUE));

AfxGetMainWnd()->GetMenu()->ModifyMenuA(0,  MF_STRING | MF_BYPOSITION, info.wID, theApp.vattingTranslation.GetDescription(256).c_str());
```

[image]

Why does it not refresh automatically my menu item "Système" ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of VS have you used to create this app?

Answer (score 3):

You need to call a [DrawMenuBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647633(v=vs.85).aspx) function afterwards as specified in the [ModifyMenu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647993(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation:

> The application must call the DrawMenuBar function whenever a menu
>   changes, whether the menu is in a displayed window.